Flyway breaking application after change Application.properties?
I have some application.properties on my project and used to be this code:
spring:
    application:
        name: MyCrudProject
    datasource:
        driver-class-name: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
        url: jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1460;databaseName=bon_dsv;sendStringParametersAsUnicode=false
        username: sa
        password: Passw0rd
    jpa:
        show-sql: true
        properties:
            hibernate:
                format_sql: true
        defer-datasource-initialization: true

I see that this is not the standard for an application.properties type... And i adjust my app.properties file to this:
spring.application.name=MyCrudProject

spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1460;databaseName=bon_dsv;sendStringParametersAsUnicode=false
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=Passw0rd

spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true
spring.jpa.defer-datasource-initialization=true

But now my Flyway gets me and error with the bean when i try to mvn install...
This is my logs:
[ERROR] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 1.645 s <<< FAILURE! -- in com.bonbap.mycrudproject.MyCrudProjectApplicationTests
[ERROR] com.bonbap.mycrudproject.MyCrudProjectApplicationTests.contextLoads -- Time elapsed: 0.009 s <<< ERROR!
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext for [WebMergedContextConfiguration@50a13c2f testClass = com.bonbap.mycrudproject.MyCrudProjectApplicationTests, locations = [], classes = [com.bonbap.mycrudproject.MyCrudProjectApplication], contextInitializerClasses = [], activeProfiles = [], propertySourceDescriptors = [], propertySourceProperties = ["org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper=true"], contextCustomizers = [org.springframework.boot.test.context.filter.ExcludeFilterContextCustomizer@5340477f, org.springframework.boot.test.json.DuplicateJsonObjectContextCustomizerFactory$DuplicateJsonObjectContextCustomizer@28cda624, org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoContextCustomizer@0, org.springframework.boot.test.web.client.TestRestTemplateContextCustomizer@66ea810, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.actuate.observability.ObservabilityContextCustomizerFactory$DisableObservabilityContextCustomizer@1f, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.properties.PropertyMappingContextCustomizer@0, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebDriverContextCustomizer@6d5620ce, org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestAnnotation@f850547e], resourceBasePath = "src/main/webapp", contextLoader = org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader, parent = null]
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:180)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:130)
    at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.setUpRequestContextIfNecessary(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:191)
    at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:130)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:260)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit.jupiter.SpringExtension.postProcessTestInstance(SpringExtension.java:163)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:197)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:179)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1625)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:509)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:499)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.StreamSpliterators$WrappingSpliterator.forEachRemaining(StreamSpliterators.java:310)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.Streams$ConcatSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Streams.java:735)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.Streams$ConcatSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Streams.java:734)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$Head.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:762)
    at java.base/java.util.Optional.orElseGet(Optional.java:364)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Failed to initialize dependency 'flyway' of LoadTimeWeaverAware bean 'entityManagerFactory': Error creating bean with name 'flyway' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/flyway/FlywayAutoConfiguration$FlywayConfiguration.class]: Circular depends-on relationship between 'flyway' and 'entityManagerFactory'
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:326)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:205)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:952)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:624)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:754)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:456)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:335)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.lambda$loadContext$3(SpringBootContextLoader.java:137)
    at org.springframework.util.function.ThrowingSupplier.get(ThrowingSupplier.java:58)
    at org.springframework.util.function.ThrowingSupplier.get(ThrowingSupplier.java:46)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.withHook(SpringApplication.java:1463)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader$ContextLoaderHook.run(SpringBootContextLoader.java:553)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:137)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:108)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:225)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:152)
    ... 17 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'flyway' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/flyway/FlywayAutoConfiguration$FlywayConfiguration.class]: Circular depends-on relationship between 'flyway' and 'entityManagerFactory'
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:308)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:313)
    ... 32 more
[INFO] 
[INFO] Results:
[INFO] 
[ERROR] Errors: 
[ERROR]   MyCrudProjectApplicationTests.contextLoads » IllegalState Failed to load ApplicationContext for [WebMergedContextConfiguration@50a13c2f testClass = com.bonbap.mycrudproject.MyCrudProjectApplicationTests, locations = [], classes = [com.bonbap.mycrudproject.MyCrudProjectApplication], contextInitializerClasses = [], activeProfiles = [], propertySourceDescriptors = [], propertySourceProperties = ["org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper=true"], contextCustomizers = [org.springframework.boot.test.context.filter.ExcludeFilterContextCustomizer@5340477f, org.springframework.boot.test.json.DuplicateJsonObjectContextCustomizerFactory$DuplicateJsonObjectContextCustomizer@28cda624, org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoContextCustomizer@0, org.springframework.boot.test.web.client.TestRestTemplateContextCustomizer@66ea810, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.actuate.observability.ObservabilityContextCustomizerFactory$DisableObservabilityContextCustomizer@1f, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.properties.PropertyMappingContextCustomizer@0, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebDriverContextCustomizer@6d5620ce, org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestAnnotation@f850547e], resourceBasePath = "src/main/webapp", contextLoader = org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader, parent = null]
[INFO] 
[ERROR] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0
[INFO] ```


This is my pom:
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
  <version>3.3.0</version>
  <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
<groupId>com.bonbap</groupId>
<artifactId>MyCrudProject</artifactId> 
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version> 
<name>MyCrudProject</name> 
<description>MyCrudProject</description> 
<properties> <java.version>17</java.version> </properties> 
<dependencies> 
<dependency> 
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId> 
</dependency> 
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
  <artifactId>flyway-core</artifactId>
  <version>10.10.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
  <artifactId>flyway-sqlserver</artifactId>
  <version>10.10.0</version> 
</dependency>   
    <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
            <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>${mssql-jdbc.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>${lombok.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.swagger.core.v3</groupId>
            <artifactId>swagger-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.11</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
            <artifactId>mapstruct</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.220</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
                <artifactId>flyway-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>10.10.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <url>jdbc:mysql://localhost:1460/bon_dsv</url>
                    <user>sa</user>
                    <password>Passw0rd</password>
                    <sqlMigrationPrefix>V</sqlMigrationPrefix>
                    <sqlMigrationSeparator>__</sqlMigrationSeparator>
                    <locations>
                        <location>filesystem:src/main/resources/db/migrations/sql</location>
                    </locations>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                    <annotationProcessorPaths>
                        <path>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId> <!-- IMPORTANT - LOMBOK BEFORE MAPSTRUCT -->
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                            <version>${lombok.version}</version>
                        </path>
                        <path>
                            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
                            <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
                            <version>1.6.0</version>
                        </path>
                    </annotationProcessorPaths>
                    <compilerArgs>
                        <compilerArg>
                            -Amapstruct.defaultComponentModel=spring
                        </compilerArg>
                    </compilerArgs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

Why i am getting this flyway error? What i have to do to the project recognize my new app.properties?  When i have my app.properties with the .yml standard, my include cant save notthing on my db... i think thats Correlated, and i am trying to solve that changing my application.properties.  if you want to see my full code the github repo is here: https://github.com/henribon/MyCrudProject/tree/master

the previous properties file was in yml format (and supposed to be called application.yml to work) and the new one you simply changed to properties format (and hopefully correctly called application.properties). Both are standard,  yml is seen as less verbose, Spring supports both. Provided that is the only thing you changed nothing should have been broken, but I am curious if you correctly named your files, since you are not familiar with yml / properties?

Error says: "Circular depends-on relationship between 'flyway' and 'entityManagerFactory'". What exactly you don't understand in this explanation?

@talexmovedtoCodidact i didnt understand what i have to do... since it wasnt a problem before, i just change the files.

Solution
You need to remove this line from application.properties file:
spring.jpa.defer-datasource-initialization=true

Reason: defering datasource initialization is not needed for Flyway and cause the error reported.
Additionally you can remove the flyway-maven-plugin section from pom.xml. The reason for this is that Spring Boot comes with out-of-the-box integration for Flyway. Spring Boot will automatically autowire Flyway with its DataSource and invoke it on startup.
Based on: https://documentation.red-gate.com/fd/community-plugins-and-integrations-spring-boot-184127423.html

removed, but still the same error. :/

Please check my updated answer.

Hey, i take off the flyway to adjust the new application.properties
Everything working fine. Now i will try to implement Flyway again.
